# hbase hive integration data type Map<String,String> with value {"-":null} is failing

Tags: hadoop, null, hive, hbase

i have a column in hbase column which is mapped to hive Map data type . now i want to populate the data using the hive but in my hive table i have the value as {"-":null} so it is failing with the exception .

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyUtils.writePrimitiveUTF8(LazyUtils.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe.serialize(HBaseSerDe.java:737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe.serialize(HBaseSerDe.java:726)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe.serializeField(HBaseSerDe.java:659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe.serialize(HBaseSerDe.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:618)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.processOp(TableScanOperator.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:519)
    ... 9 more
```

If I am trying to insert using `str_to_map('{"-":null}',',',':')` then it is working fine. 
Please help me with the issue